# Retreive specific values from file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a file test.cf containing:

```
   process {

        withName : teq {

            file = "/path/to/teq-0.20.9.txt"

        }

    }

   process {

        withName : cad {

            file = "/path/to/cad-4.0.txt"

        }

    }

   process {

        withName : sik {

            file = "/path/to/sik-20.0.txt"

        }

    }
```

I would like to retreive value associated at the end of the file for teq, cad and sik

I was first thinking about something like

```
grep -E 'teq' test.cf
```

and get only second raw and then remove part of recurrence in line

But it may be easier to do something like:

```
for a in test.cf
do 
line=$(sed -n '{$a}p' test.cf)

if line=teq
#next line using sed -n?
    do print nextline &> teq.txt
else if line=cad
    do print nextline &> cad.txt
else if line=sik
    do print nextline &> sik.txt
done
```

(obviously it doesn't work)

EDIT:

output wanted:
teq.txt containing `teq-0.20.9`, cad.txt containing `cad-4.0` and sik.txt containing `sik-20.0`

Is there a good way to do that? Thank you for your comments

Comment: Can you add the exact output required for the given sample?

Comment: Your input looks like JSON, would `jq` not be a better tool than `grep`?

Comment: good idea! I've tried: it works if I take only part of the file which is not JSON format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution in awk:

```sh
awk '/withName/{name=$3} /file =/{print $3 > name ".txt"}' test.cf
```

- `/withName/{name=$3}`: when I see the line containing "withName", I save that name
- When I see the line with "file =", I print

Comment: sounds a very interesting solution but I can't retreive the names (tek,..). thought it was a space or tabulation problem so I change $ value without success

Comment: It must be tab vs space issue. I copied your sample test.cf to my machine and it seems to work fine.

Comment: it works for me! thanks a lot! `awk -v FS='\t' -v OFS='\t' '/withName/{name=$3} /file =/{print $3 > name ".txt"}' test.cf `

Answer (score 2):

Based on your given sample:

```sh
awk '/withName/{close(f); f=$3 ".txt"}
     /file/{sub(/.*\//, ""); sub(/\.txt".*/, "");
            print > f}' ip.txt
```

- `/withName/{close(f); f=$3 ".txt"}` if line contains `withName`, save filename in `f` using the third field. `close()` will close any previous file handle
- `/file/{sub(/.*\//, ""); sub(/\.txt".*/, "");` if line contains `file`, remove everything except the value required
- `print > f` print the modified line and redirect to filename in `f`

  - if you can have multiple entries, use `>>` instead of `>`